# Buscador PHP Y SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, php7

Tengo un buscador que me consulta datos, en una base de datos de sql server,
la conexión da con un servidor, pero lo que quiero es

necesito crear un buscador que me consulte en 27 servidores diferentes
es decir que cuando yo ingrese el #doc a consultar me aparezca

espero me halla dado a entender

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega las dudas técnicas puntuales; es decir ya trataste algo? que problemas has tenido?

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, me recomendaron la pagina y soy nuevo, claro ya cree el buscador y me funciona correctamente...

Comment: lo que deseo es que, ese buscador me consulte en 27 servidores , para no tener que crear el mismo buscador para consulta uno por uno

Comment: En 27 servidores de BD? 27 servidores de aplicación? No se entiende y tampoco sabemos cuál es la arquitectura de depsliegue de tu aplicación, como para sugerir la mejor opción para resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr eso necesitas conectarte a cada uno de las instancias de SQL Server en las que requieres buscar. Si ese tipo de consultas es común, una buena opción sería configurar un servidor de administración central (Central Management Server) y un grupo de servidores. De esta forma, sólo tendrías que conectarte al servidor de administración central y ese servidor creará conexiones simultaneas al grupo de servidores para realizar las consultas.

[La documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-central-management-server-and-server-group) tiene información de como realizarlo.

Comment: Mil gracias, voy a intentarlo

Comment: Lo intente, y ya lo cree, todo aparenta funcionar muy bien, que pasa cuando ya intento conectar esto en mi codigo, tengo lo siguiente:

Comment: $serverName = "ip-servidor";
   $userName = "usuario";
   $userPassword = "password";
   $dbName = "Grupo";
pero al ejecutar me sale erro en la conexion odbc , ya me conecte pero no me aparece ese grupo, como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Necesitas compartir más información de lo que estás haciendo para saber que es lo que pasa.

Answer (score -2):

amigo que servidor local estas usando, te recomiendo que uses MAMP para que te conectes a la base de datos y vincules parametros e aqui un ejemplo, ademas te dejo un video chekea :)...

```
   <?php

     $link = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yt_colores';
     $usuario = 'root';
     $pass = 'root';

       try {
       $pdo = new PDO($link,$usuario,$pass);
       echo 'conectado <br>';

      }catch (PDOException $e){
       print "error!:".$e->getMessage(). "<br/>";
       die();
      }
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9glSpdwygdk&t=10s

Comment: -1 el OP claramente indica usar SQL Server, además de eso el habla sobre una conexión a múltiples servidores por lo cual esto no aplica